# Is there a function to upload with github actions on a release the builded jar to github?

Tags: maven, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

i want to upload on a release the builded jar of my maven project on a release commit but i have no plan what im doing. My action at this moment looks like this:

```
name: Java CI

on: [push, release]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
    - name: Upload to release
      if: github.event == 'release'
      uses: JasonEtco/upload-to-release@master
      with:
        args: target/MyGreatJavaSoftware.jar
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

but if i make an release it fires 3 times and in this 3 times the Upload to release step is skipped.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if: github.event_name == 'release'`?

Comment: @Samira i think you have right but in the example of Github Actions they use `if: github.event == 'push'` but in the documentation stands `github.event` needs a object and `github.event_name` needs a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @[Samira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11998612/samira) says it should be `if: github.event_name == 'release'`.
And i find out that it fires multiple times because release has more than one type. So now my final Github Action looks like this:

```
name: Java CI
on:
  push:
  release:
    types: [published]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
    - name: Upload to Release
      if: github.event_name == 'release'
      uses: JasonEtco/upload-to-release@master
      with:
        args: target/MyGreatJavaSoftware.jar application/java-archive
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```